# Can't build 32 bit asp.net app deployment package on 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment-project, x86-64

I'm building a web app that's going to be deployed on a 32 bit server, using a cproj_deploy and web deployment project to build my msi file. If I build this on XP, everything works fine. If I build it on Windows 7, I get the following error. 
File 'BridgeService.dll' of project output 'Precompiled Web Outputs from BridgeService.csproj_deploy (Active)' 
targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
C:\projects\bridge\PDMSCoreWebService\PDMSCoreWebService.vdproj

If I go into Configuration Manager, the csproj_deploy is set to "Any CPU". If I try to edit the platform, I don't have any options. (Any CPU is my only choice.) The active solution platform for the configuration is x86.
How do I force my deployment project to compile 32 bit?

Comment: Do you have to force it to 32 bit? I believe the default compile should load ok on 32 bit machines unless you specifically have interop concerns/native calling code, etc on the build?

Comment: While it claims that it's "Any CPU," the deployment project (.vdproj) is getting a 64 bit DLL from the web deployment project (csproj_deploy) and that stops the build.

Answer (score 0):

Manually Clearing out all of the obj files appears to have done the trick. Apparently Clean Solution and Rebuild Solution aren't reliable.

Comment: what was changed that wouldve changed your obj files?